# Import and parse .csv files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nan

I have a folder which contains a number of .csv files. In the first row of each .csv file, there is 49 parameters name and in all other rows there are 49 values for those parameters. I need to read each file and separate parameters and its corresponding values. If one value is empty, I need to put a `NaN` and then zero instead of that. The code that I wrote works fine for all parameters except the second column (second parameter), which its value are date and time, my code put `NaN` for all values of this parameter.

Here is my code:

```
for h = 1:numel(CSVfiles)   % h is number of CSV files in the coresponding folder

    delimiter = '\t';
    formatSpec = '%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%[^\n\r]';

    fileID = fopen(CSVfiles(h,1).name,'r');
    dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter,  'ReturnOnError', false);
    fclose(fileID);

    for i=1:49
        C(1,i)= dataArray(1,i);
    end

    C =cellfun(@str2double,C,'un',0);

    VarName1 = cell2mat(C(:,1));      % for this column it works fine
    VarName1(isnan(VarName1)) = 0 ;
    VarName2 = cell2mat(C(:,2));      % for this column it replaces all values with zero!
    VarName2(isnan(VarName2)) = 0 ;

    end
```

Comment: Your line 'C =cellfun(@str2double,C,'un',0);' tries to convert every string read to double precision number. This fails when trying to convert a date string. You might use the function 'datenum' for this column. You can probably also use '%f' in your 'formatSpec' when using textscan, this way you'll read the numbers directly. It is not possible to give you a correct example code if you don't include an example of the csv lines you are reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, column two is date and time, while the others are scalar numeric values, right?

The problem may be caused by trying to parse the date/time string using `str2double`. Try using `datenum` on that column instead (you'll need to specify the date/time format type, see the documentation for `datenum`).